# Time delay before redirect

Tags: c#, timedelay

I create a register page for my web application. The application require that after user successfully register a new account, the page will show a message "Register successfully", then wait for 5 seconds before switch to Login page. I used `Thread.Sleep(5000)`. It wait for 5 seconds but it does not display the message. Can anyone help me?

```
void AccountServiceRegisterCompleted(object sender, RegisterCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Register successfully";

            Thread.Sleep(5000); 
            this.SwitchPage(new Login());
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: ASP .NET WebForms? MVC? Other? Please tag appropriately as it affects the answers you'll receive.

Comment: Why do you not redirect immediately to the register page, with a flag which says 'Register Successful'; Redirecting with a GET parameter of ?register=true or something to show the flag is enough. This is also much more user friendly.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep(5000)` only suspends your thread for 5 seconds - no code onto this thread will be executed during this time. So no messages or anything else.

If it's an ASP.NET app, client doesn't know what's going on on server and waits server's response for 5 seconds. You have to implement this logic manually. For example, either using JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function(){location.href = 'test.aspx';}, 5000);
```

or by adding HTTP header:

```
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH","5;URL=test.aspx");
```

or `meta` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=test.aspx" />
```

see [more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header).

If it's a desktop application you could use something like [timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). And never make main thread (UI Thread) hangs with something like Thread.Sleep.

Comment: Thank you Lorond, the explanation is very clear and easy to understand. I will try using these suggestions.

Comment: What if it is a login form and it is inside an updatepanel? I tried the above method and it did not redirect me :/

Answer (score 0):

Only meta tag is enough to redirect to another page

ad meta tag dynamically

`Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "5;URL=~/account/login");`

This code will ad a meta tag to current page and your page will redirect to another page in specified  time like above.